How to upload and test an Excel add-in using Azure blob storage
I've developed an Excel Add-In which, as I understand it, I need to upload to an Azure blob storage and generate an URL with a SAS key that I then share with the certification team.  This will be a transactable offer that will be available in AppSource upon approval by the certification team.  I have only run this app locally either using "npm start" in a PowerShell, in VS Code "run and debug", and in a local shared folder as an Excel add as a Trusted Add-In catalog.  My question is, can I run my app from a blob storage and how do I do that, and do I need to do something special about the SAS key to get it to work.  My hope is I can basically run the app in the same way that the certification team will run it so I can test it the exact same way they will.  I've been looking at this link but its not clear to me how to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/appsource/store-package-azure-storage
Thanks for any advice you can provide.
I tried uploading my Excel add in dist folder contents to Azure blob storage, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to reference this in my manifest or how to deal with the URL SAS key.

Change the URLs in the manifest to point to the Azure URLs. To test that your add-in runs from the Azure host, sideload the new manifest in any of the ways you mentioned.
Then follow the instructions in Submit to AppSource via Partner Center.

I got it figured out.  I followed these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-add-in-vs-code and got it working.  I did have to go to my Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and copy the links there, the instructions left out the $web part of the links.  I'm a happy camper now.
